# Check if element has attribute

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I'm trying to create extension method that checks if specific object has specific attribute.

I've found example that checks it with the following syntax:

```
private static bool IsMemberTested(MemberInfo member)
{
foreach (object attribute in member.GetCustomAttributes(true))
    {
        if (attribute is IsTestedAttribute)
        {
           return true;
        }
    }
return false;
}
```

Now I'm trying to do the following:

```
    public static bool HasAttribute<T>(this T instance, Type attribute)
    {
        return typeof(T).GetCustomAttributes(true).Any(x => x is attribute);
    }
```

However I get the message 'The type or namespace 'attribute' is missing...'

What am I doing wrong and different from given example / how can I make this happen?

EDIT:

Thanks for the tips, I've managed to do it like this now:

```
    public static bool HasAttribute<T>(this T instance, Type attribute)
    {
        return typeof(T).GetCustomAttributes(attribute, true).Any();
    }
```

And checking for attribute goes like this:

```
var cc = new CustomClass();
var nullable = cc.HasAttribute(typeof(NullableAttribute));
```

Thanks for help guys. Now I have another question. Say I want to decorate a property of the class, property of type string, with an attribute, and want to check later on if that property has an attribute. Since this works only with types, I can't apply it on property level. Is there any solution to property check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a `Type` variable as the argument of an `is` operator.  Moreover, there's no need to use `Any` to filter this yourself, since there's an overload of `GetCustomAttributes` that will do it for you.

I've written this extension method for similar functionality (mine is to return the single attribute appllied to a class):

```
    internal static AttributeType GetSingleAttribute<AttributeType>(this Type type) where AttributeType : Attribute
    {
        var a = type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AttributeType), true);
        return (AttributeType)a.SingleOrDefault();
    }
```

You could modify this to return a boolean value `a != null` instead to get what you're looking for.

Comment: This is sweet, I was doing this the brute force and ignorance way. I just changed Dan's extension to return a bool. return type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TAttributeType), true).Any();

Answer (score 0):

I've made solution on how to check property attribute even for simple types:

```
    public static bool HasPropertyAttribute<T>(this T instance, string propertyName, Type attribute)
    {
        return Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName), attribute, true).Any();
    }
```

Invoking goes like this:

```
var cc = new CustomClass();
cc.HasPropertyAttribute("Name", typeof(NullableAttribute));
```